# How to generate 5-digit random integers where not all digits take 0 - 9?

Tags: r, random

I want to generate `n` (sample size) number of 5-digit random integers, with the following requirements:

1. the 1st digit denotes "Group", which is either 1 or 2
2. the 2nd digit denotes "version", which is either 1 or 2
3. the last 3 digits are random integers ranging from 001 to 999.

How can I do this?

---

**update**

How can I ensure that there are equal number of 1 and 2 in the 1st digit, as well as in the 2nd digit? I want even `n` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample.int(2, n, TRUE) * 1e+4 +
sample.int(2, n, TRUE) * 1e+3 +
sample.int(999, n, TRUE)
```

where `n` is sample size, say 100.

> How can I ensure that there are equal number of 1 and 2 in the 1st digit, as well as in the 2nd digit? I want even `n` only.

```
my5digits <- function (n) {
  if (n %% 2) stop("n must be even!")
  x1 <- sample(rep_len(c(1, 2), n))
  x2 <- sample(x1)
  x1 * 1e+4 + x2 * 1e+3 + sample.int(999, n, TRUE)
  }

set.seed(0)
my5digits(10)
# [1] 11777 11934 21212 12652 22126 21267 22386 22014 12383 11869
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sample` and `paste0`

```
set.seed(505)
d1.group <- sample(c(1,2), 100, replace = TRUE)  # first number denoting Group
d2.version <- sample(c(1,2), 100, replace = TRUE) # second number for version
d3.any <- sprintf("%03.0f", sample(sample(c(1,999), 100, replace = TRUE))) # last 3 ditigs
as.numeric(paste0(d1.group, d2.version, d3.any)) # put them altogether

  [1] 11001 22001 11999 12999 11999 22999 11999 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 12001 22999 22001 22999 21999 12999 21001
 [21] 12001 22001 11001 12999 12999 12001 11999 21001 22999 21001 22001 11001 22001 12999 22001 21001 21001 12999 12999 12001
 [41] 12001 22999 11999 11999 22999 11999 21001 12999 22001 21999 21001 11999 11999 12999 21999 22999 22001 22001 22999 11001
 [61] 11999 12001 22999 21999 11001 11999 11999 21999 22999 22999 11999 11999 21999 11001 12999 22001 11001 11999 21001 21999
 [81] 11001 11999 12001 11001 22001 22001 21001 12999 12001 21999 21999 21999 11999 22999 11999 21001 12999 22001 21001 11999
```